# What is "Excessive resource usage" in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I searched online for awhile about what is "Excessive resource usage" on SQL Azure, still cannot get an idea.

Some articles suggest query takes too long, too much memory etc will cause "Excessive resource usage". But If I use simple query, simple data structure, what will happen?

For example: I get a 1G SQL Azure as session state. Since session is a very small string, and save/delete all the time, I don't think it will grow to 1G for millions of session simultaneously. You can calculate, for 1 million session, 20 char each, only take 20M space, consider 20 minutes expire etc. Cannot even close to 1G. But the queries, should be lots and lots. Each query will be very simple and fast by index.

I wanna know, if this use will be consider as "Excessive resource usage"? Is there any hard number to limit you on the usage?

Btw, as example above, if all happen in same datacenter, so all cost is 1G database which is $10 a month, right?

Comment: Please remember that storing session in SQL Azure isn't supported but if you really want to do it, take a look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/04/10046103.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tom, I am not going to store session there. I just use it as an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is 'it depends'. I think that probably the best reference (with guidance) on the SQL Azure Query Throttle is here: [TechNet Article on SQL Azure Perormance](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-performance-and-elasticity-guide.aspx) This will povide details about the metrics that are monitored and the mechanism of the throttle.

The reason that I say it depends is that the throttle is non-deterministic for any given user. This is because the throttle will be activated based on the total load on the node (physical SQL Server in Azure DC). While the subscribers who will get throttled are the subscribers delivering the greatest load the level at which the throttle kicks in will depend on the total load on the node. SO if you are on a quiet node (where other tenant DBs are relatively inactive) then you will be able to put through a bunch more throughput than if you are on a busy node.

It is very appealing to use 1GB SQL Azure DBs for session state storage; you've identified the cost benefits. You are taking a risk though. One way to mitigate this risk is to partition across at least two SQL Azure 1GB DBs and adjust the load yourself based on whether one of the DBs starts hitting the throttle.

Another option if you want determinism for throughput is to use the WIndows Azure Cache to back your sesion state store. The Cache has hard pre-defined limits for query throughput so you can plan for it more easily [Azure Caching FAQ including Limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697522.aspx#C_BKMK_FAQ8). The Cache approach is probably a bit more expensive but with a lower risk of problems.

Comment: There's no mechanism to allow your session state to be partitioned across different SQL Azure databases.

Comment: Sort of a-m on SQL1, and n-z on SQL2 solution. Not dynamic

Comment: @Chris, distribution is a good idea. However, how to know if DB starts to hit throttle? Lots of 503 error?

Comment: Hi David. Actually ASP.NET Session state from version 2.0 has native support for partitioning by implementing IPartitionResolver. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx#S8 I have not done an implementation of this that does federations yet, but, I have done an implementation that just partitioned across my on pre-defined set of SQL Azure Databases.

Comment: And one other point of follow up in terms of throughput. Having done a bit of poking around at SQL Azure under load (and with the caveat that it's non-deterministic) I'd be reasonably confident of a few hundred requests per second on your session table.